# i need help with a crowdsale contract

Tags: solidity

Ethereum lib direct crowdsale provided by modular . When trying to call function init . I get the storage argument wrong. Can I get help? With an example maybe

Comment: Please post more details. What contract are you trying to use? What parameters are you giving? How are you calling it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.